# Is there any completely Computation Drug ever launched in market?

Tags: pharmacology

I am working in bioinformatics(part of it in Drug Designing) for years, still if I have no idea about it. As it is too hard to prove (Pass all Clinical trials) and get FDA Approvals.

So, My question is there a drug available in market, which is actually designed computationally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are a few. Mostly they are designed in combination with X-ray crystallography of the target which should be inhibited. Then molecules are designed which fit specifically into these targets.

The oldest example I could find is Dorzolamide which acts as a carbonic anhydrase inhibitor. See here: "[Application of the three-dimensional structures of protein target molecules in structure-based drug design.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8164249)"
Some more examples are names in the Wikipedia article on [drug design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_design#Examples).

While looking for an example, I found these articles, which also look interesting:

- [Molecular Modeling and Computer Aided Drug Design. Examples of their
  Applications in Medicinal Chemistry](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/ben/cmc/2000/00000007/00000002/art00001)
- [Computer-based de novo design of drug-like molecules](http://www.nature.com/nrd/journal/v4/n8/abs/nrd1799.html)
- [Recent advances in computer-aided drug design](http://bib.oxfordjournals.org/content/10/5/579.short)

I am also not sure, to what extent the modern small molecule inhibitors like Vemurafenib (PLX4032) and others are designed using computers. At least to some extent this should be true.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this was the question which almost stopped getting my current job!!(Though I got it finally). Still there are 4-5 drugs as per my boss. So, if you find them, sure add to the list.

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia page I linked. There are some more examples listed (although I haven't checked all of them).